# How to stop sanitize-html from encoding HTML entities?

Tags: node.js, html-sanitizing

I am using the [sanitize-html package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) on Node.js to sanitize user input.

The problem I am facing is that sanitize-html is automatically encoding/escaping certain characters. This is an example:

```
const sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');
const TitleText = 'Nintendo & Microsoft & Sony';
console.log('Before', TitleText);
const TitleTextSanitized = sanitizeHtml(TitleText, {allowedTags: []})
console.log('After', TitleTextSanitized);
```

The first `console.log` output is:

```
Before: Nintendo & Microsoft & Sony
```

After sanitizing it ends up becoming:

```
After: Nintendo &amp; Microsoft &amp; Sony
```

I do not want HTML escaped characters in my database and I cannot seem to find a way to stop this from happening.

Comment: `&amp;` is what it should be for html. But sake of argument, you can simply replace it back `console.log('After', TitleTextSanitized.replace(/&amp;/g, '&'));`, I suspect it will change £ into &pounds; etc so you might simply not want to use that lib, or do *sanitation* on output rather than on input